# DISCORD.PY For Loop Channel ID Purge

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
for x in channels:
      time.sleep(interval)
      await ctx.channel.purge(x)
```

I have this code which loops through a array with channel ID's. Only issue is its not working whatsoever. I just get a blank error.

Comment: You're calling purge on `ctx.channel` instead of the `x` variable. Also, what do you mean with "I just get a blank error"? And what does the `channels` variable look like? Are they IDs or `discord.Channel` instances?

Comment: Do you wish to delete channels in the server/guild?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.